# DROP a table using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I want execute `drop` table query on my database using spring JPA (Database- `Postgres`)

This is my code:

```
public void executeDropTable(String tableName){

    String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS :tableName";

    entityManager.createQuery(query)
            .setParameter("tableName", tableName)
            .executeUpdate();

}
```

But in IntelliJ shows error as `'DROP' unexpected` on a query string

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute a Create Table Query through the JPA EntityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141794/execute-a-create-table-query-through-the-jpa-entitymanager)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get something like this:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
>   DROP near line 1, column 1 [DROP TABLE webinar_speakers]

The `DROP` statement is not valid HQL.

Use a native query instead and don't forget `@Transactional`:

```
@Transactional
public void executeDropTable(String tableName) {
    // ...
    entityManager.createNativeQuery(...) // ...
}
```

---

The fact that `DROP` is highlighted most likely comes from the Spring Data plugin for IntelliJ which "knows" that `DROP` is not valid in this context. If you use `createNativeQuery(...)` `DROP` won't be highlighted anymore.

Comment: I noticed that when I annotate the method with @transactional. it gets invoked even when I am not invoking the method

Answer (score 1):

EntityManager.createQuery will cannot used for DML Statements. Use EntityManager.createNativeQuery.